# Pushing notifications continuously w/ SignalR and ASP.NET MVC (realtime)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to figure out how I can setup continuous realtime notifications to a page using SignalR.

All of the samples/tutorials I find with SignalR are with a textbox and a send button. When text is sent, it is displayed to all clients. Instead of this I need to continuously post notifications where NotificationStartDateTime = DateTime.Now().

Would my GetNotifications() function that calls the repository go in my NotificationsHub class? Additionally, how can I continuously call it and receive the results on the client.

**Here is my current client code:**

```
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var hub = $.connection.notificationsHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast notifications.
        hub.client.broadcastNotifications= function (notifications) {
            alert(reminders[0].title);
        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            // Call the GetNotifications method on the hub. 
            hub.server.getNotifications();
        });
```

Comment: What do you want to actually trigger the notifications? Some user action on your site? A database table being updated?

Comment: @mason I just updated my post with my current client-side code. I am not sure if there is a trigger. The trigger would basically be: If there are notifications in the database where CreateByUserId=CurrentLoggedInUserId and NotificationDate = DateTime.Now() then I want to notify the user of the notification while they are using the application. I believe I am close to figuring this out. I am aware that typically there is some sort of trigger, but in my case the triggers would be based of data in the database..

Comment: What you have now isn't real time. It's a single check to get notifications. You could have easily done that with AJAX or just included it with the HTML from MVC. So that doesn't answer my question. What I'm interested in is *what creates the notifications?*

Comment: @mason Ok disregard the notifications concept. Lets pretend there are a bunch of reminders that were created last week and are stored in the database. If the user is logged in during the ReminderDate I want to notify them of the reminder.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this right, @BlakeRivell wants to create the notifications based off some logic some event / logic from the database. If that is the case, then Notifications using SignalR and SQL Dependency seems to be what is needed.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras hmm yes it seems like SQL Dependency is the term I was looking for. So how would a system like this typically work, can you give me a general idea? I already have SignalR setup.

Comment: In that case I recommend some sort of [background process](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) that is constantly running (or constantly querying the database). It would be responsible for talking to SignalR to notify a user. If you look at the link I provided, you can put this background stuff directly in your site. Or you could have a separate service running external to your site.

Comment: @mason I will look into background processes. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what your environment is and how often you need to check if a notification should be generated. Let's say you just need to check every 15 minutes. Then a console app and a Windows Scheduled Task could do the job. If you need to check every 15 seconds, then perhaps you need a full blown Windows Service (preferably installed with [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)).

Comment: @mason it sounds crazy but these notifications need to be pretty much instant, kind of like a calendar event notification on your phone. If you add an event to your calendar and choose to be notified 2 hours before, the notification should pop up 2 hours before exactly. Maybe this HangFire app will help me.

Comment: @mason Actually what the heck am I talking about. Seconds are not a factor with these notifications so it would be every minute.

Comment: From the client perspective, you'll need a way to check if a notification is already there. You can do that when SignalR first connects. Then at that point you just need to listen for new notifications. Something has to "push" the notification. SignalR Hubs are just the glue between the pusher (your background task) and the recipient (the client's browser).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131095/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-mason).